# Can we remove the synonym link between tags ‘appmenu’ and ‘applications-menu’?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [appmenu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/appmenu) tag is for the global application menu AKA `appmenu-indicator`, that allows screen real estate to be conserved in desktop environments (DE's, AKA ‘graphical shells’) that support it. The [applications-menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/applications-menu) tag seems to be a better fit for the launcher menu ‘Applications’ found in various DE's, especially since the tag has an ‘s’.

I propose that a new tag [global-application-menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/global-application-menu) be a synonym for [appmenu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/appmenu), and that [applications-menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/applications-menu) becomes a ‘primary’ tag in its own right referring to the applications launcher menu.

---

History:

```
appmenu × 192       applications-menu   jokerdino♦   jun 13 '12 at 14:11    0
indicator × 666     appindicator × 6    jokerdino♦   jun 25 '12 at 15:34    27  jun 14 at 8:41
```

Possible Miss-tagged questions (usage cases for [applications-menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/applications-menu) that don't fit description of [appmenu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/appmenu))

https://askubuntu.com/questions/284424/xfce-is-there-a-way-to-make-super-not-open-my-app-menu-when-using-superr
https://askubuntu.com/questions/274487/is-lxpanel-compatible-with-unity
[Where is the Applications menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262780/where-is-the-applications-menu)
[What desktop environments feature a searchable "Start" menu/launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233596/what-desktop-environments-feature-a-searchable-start-menu-launcher)
[How do I move items in the Applications (or Main) Menu Around?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229349/how-do-i-move-items-in-the-applications-or-main-menu-around)

and more.

---

Other tag currently in use that might need consideration: [globalmenu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/globalmenu)

Globalmenu is related but distinctly separate. appmenu is prevalent across DE's whereas globalmenu is Gnome only. People often call ‘appmenu’ ‘globalmenu’ (the reverse is not so true), so having global-application-menu would both appear in suggestions when typing ‘global’, and further distinguish from applications-menu.

Comment: [tag:globalmenu] is related but distinctly separate. appmenu is prevalent across DE's whereas [tag:globalmenu] is Gnome only. People often call ‘appmenu’ ‘globalmenu’ (the reverse is not so true), so having [tag:global-application-menu] would both appear in suggestions when typing ‘global’, and further distinguish from [tag:applications-menu].

Comment: Please *edit* all relevant information into your question. Comments are for discussion about the question itself ;-)

Comment: So is globalmenu being misused a lot?

Comment: @mateo: Doesn't seem to be, maybe helped by its tag wiki entry saying “This is NOT the global menu shipped in Unity.”, but [tag:appmenu] is misused so often that a significant portion of the questions I've seen tagged [tag:appmenu] are talking about an applications menu. (Hence my concern to report here. ;-) Do people just not read the tag wiki popups for [tag:appmenu], or was [tag:applications-menu] incorrectly made to be a synonym after these questions were asked?

Comment: @Seth: I'm confused, I thought I was discussing; I was replying to mateo's edit.

Comment: that is why it said "might need consideration" because it is named similarly. I was concerned the new tag might get confused with it, so we should probably help distinguish between them with the other tag. Also I think that making it a synonym merged the questions, can't tell how many were misused now that they are merged, so I can only assume that most happened because of the merge.

Comment: @mateo: I don't understand why synonyms have to be remapped. Why not just preserve the original synonym, but treat as one in tag searches, counts, etc.. Or have ‘subtags’ such that e.g. [tag:gnome-shell] is a subtag of [tag:gnome], like subcategories on Wikipedia.

Comment: @JamesHaigh Ah, OK. In that case you should prefix your comment with `@mateo` so he gets a notification and so we know what and who you are talking to ;-)

Comment: @Seth: Oh, yeah, that makes more sense now. Sorry about that.

Comment: @JamesHaigh No problem :)